# GoogleScript getSheetbyName error null - How do I solve it?

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function SendGoogleForm(e) 
{   

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName('sheetname').getLastRow().getValue();
    var found = false;

    for ( var keys in sheet ) {
        if ( e.target[5] < "3" ) {
            found = true; 
            var email = "email@email.com"
            var subject ="Needs action"
            var message = "Hi Take action!"
        }
    }

    if (found) 
        MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);

}
```

I try to run this script, based on Google Form entry, if in collumn E an entry is < 3 then it should send an email.

However I get consent an error

> Cannot call method "getSheetName" of null. (line 4, file "Code")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means [getActiveSpreadsheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getActiveSpreadsheet()) returns `null`, which means you have a [standalone script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone). Either move this to a script [bound to your desired spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound), or retrieve the spreadsheet via [openById](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openById(String)) or [openByUrl](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#openbyurlurl). This last option would mean changing this line:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() // ...
```

To this one:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID') // ...
```

Or, alternatively, this one:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('SPREADSHEET_URL') // ...
```

#### Other issues:

If you fix that, though, you will then encounter other errors, since:

- You're calling the method [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) on an integer (returned by [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getlastrow), - `.getLastRow().getValue();`). `getValue()` is a method of [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range) instead.
- You are trying to iterate through an element (`sheets`) which you want to retrieve with an invalid method (`.getLastRow().getValue();`, as mentioned before). Your code wouldn't get that far without changing that, but in any case, `sheets` should be an object with enumerable properties (see [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)).
- No [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) related to an `onFormSubmit` trigger has a `target` property.

#### Solution:

If I understand you correctly, you want to do the following when a Form is submitted:

- Look for a number in column E (in sheet `sheetname`) which is lower than 3.
- If a number is found, send email.

In this case, you can do the following (assuming that you have installed the trigger):

```
function SendGoogleForm(e) {     
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetName('sheetname').getDataRange().getValues();
  const found = values.filter(row => typeof row[4] == "number").some(row => row[4] < 3);  
  if (found) {
    const email = "email@email.com";
    const subject ="Needs action";
    const message = "Hi Take action!";
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message);  
  }
};
```

#### Further reading:

- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you.

How can I get more values from the form submit? I want to get into the email body column 5, 6 and 7.

I try to use var conten5 = e[5] and other methods I find through reading but no success .

Comment: @Artem You `e.values` or `e.namedValues` for that, depending on whether you want to use indexes or item names. In your case, you want to use indexes, or it should be, for example `e.values[5]` (see [Event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit)). If you need more details, I'd suggest you to post a new answer.